# Naive Bayes e1071 classifies every surname as the same ancestry

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-classification, naivebayes

I am a newbie and I wish to use a Naive Bayes classifier to identify ancestry based on the 3-gram of surnames of individuals.

Strangely, the code bellow classifies (most) surnames as Japanese ancestry- JPN .

```
library(e1071)
library(caret)
test <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/116353/test.csv", header=T)
test <- test[,-1]
train <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/116353/train.csv", header=T)
train <- train[,-1]
model  <- naiveBayes(nation~., data=train, laplace=1) 
predictions <- predict(model, newdata=test[,-1], threshold = 0.01)
confusionMatrix(predictions, test$nation)
```

Some clues:

When I increase the size of the training set the problem get worse and everybody is classified as JPN;

I am pretty sure that the data is fine, because I tested other classifiers (SVM and Carvar & Trenkle) and they performed ok.
Thank you!

Comment: Just realized there is something awkward with your ngrams. The first test example has the two ngrams 'ato' and 'ena'. If you have two 3grams they should have a two letters overlap. I'm assuming you've split a six letter words in two halves? However the four letter string user should become 'use' and 'ser'

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. In fact, I removed sparse terms in my training and test sets. Otherwise, I would have more than 4600 features in the training set and 2800 in the test set. I tested with the full set of ngrams and there was no change in the accuracy.

Comment: Normally the parameter `eps` and `threshold` should take care of this. I debuged the code of the naive Bayes a bit further (c.f. my answer below) and I must say it looks awkward. When you do the removal you should make sure you are consistent! See also my answer below ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the probabilities you will figure that

```
> predictions <- predict(model, newdata=test[,-1], threshold = 0.01,type="raw")
> head(predictions)
               EAS          GER           IBR           ITA JAP
[1,] 1.836872e-109 1.535376e-40 2.058015e-228 1.351274e-124   1
[2,] 1.286083e-276 1.133225e-45  0.000000e+00 2.507828e-157   1
[3,] 4.008149e-163 1.257501e-87 3.181309e-136 7.501385e-191   1
[4,]  2.477674e-71 2.008653e-85  0.000000e+00 9.385175e-133   1
[5,] 1.539279e-289 6.367960e-23 1.251711e-114 1.656610e-149   1
[6,]  2.359038e-95 6.367960e-23 3.390903e-110 8.556824e-156   1
```

This looks really awkward.

Inspecting the learned probabilities does not provide real insides on the first sight:

```
head(t(as.data.frame(model$tables)))
              EAS       GER         IBR         ITA        JAP
acc.1 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.002253944 0.016165245 0.00000000
acc.2 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.047440015 0.126124942 0.00000000
ach.1 0.011730205 0.0154321 0.006010518 0.003816794 0.00931677
ach.2 0.107721635 0.1234544 0.077323244 0.061669116 0.09614740
ada.1 0.002932551 0.0000000 0.006010518 0.002694207 0.03105590
ada.2 0.054100023 0.0000000 0.077323244 0.051841606 0.17360366
```

So lets look at the feature of the first example

```
 head(test[,test[1,]==1])
  ato ena
1   1   1
```

Next inspect the number of times the feature occur in the train data:

```
> tail(cumsum(train[,c("ato","ena")]))
Error in `[.data.frame`(train, , c("ato", "ena")) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

**OPPSY** (technical term for WTF) Actually it is ena

Appearently you have feature in your test set which do not occur in your training set. Resorting to the last factor element is not uncommon in implementing ML models.

You should use a smaller n-gram length, use something like Katz-back of estimates or filter the test data to feature only occurring in the training set.

Your strategy on increasing the threshold wasn't bad.

```
predictions <- predict(model, newdata=test[,-1], threshold = 0.1)
 confusionMatrix(predictions, test$nation)
          Reference
Prediction EAS GER IBR ITA JAP
       EAS 166  49 127 280  77
       GER  10   7  24  88   5
       IBR  39  11 152 223  29
       ITA  15   3  31 419   4
       JAP  11   4  21  87  62

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.4146
```